# Scribe strange uncontrolled exception with Twitter

Tags: scribe

I'm pretty new to Scribe but when i try to auth through Twitter a weird error rises up.
My code is pretty much the same than the TwitterExample:

```
        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(TwitterApi.class)
            .apiKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX<<custom>>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .apiSecret("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY<<custom>>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY")
            .debug()
            .build();

        Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

        Log.i("OAUTH LINK", service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));

        Verifier verifier = new Verifier("verifier you got from the user");
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        response = request.send();
        Log.i("OAUTH RESPONSE",response.getBody());
```

And the debug output returned is:

I/System.out(1776): obtaining request token from http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

I/System.out(1776): setting oauth_callback to oob

I/System.out(1776): generating signature...

I/System.out(1776): using base64 encoder: CommonsCodec

I/System.out(1776): base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D1095830595%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1391024186%26oauth_version%3D1.0

I/System.out(1776): signature is: In0u/SlHz9cr5NLAQK56kALJ3hI=

I/System.out(1776): appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> In0u/SlHz9cr5NLAQK56kALJ3hI= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 1095830595 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX , oauth_timestamp -> 1391024186 }

I/System.out(1776): using Http Header signature

I/System.out(1776): sending request...

D/dalvikvm(1776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 3% free 13188K/13575K, paused 134ms

I/System.out(1776): response status code: 403

I/System.out(1776): response body:

W/System.err(1776): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from an empty string**

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.utils.Preconditions.check(Preconditions.java:84)

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.utils.Preconditions.checkEmptyString(Preconditions.java:44)

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:26)

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:64)

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:40)

W/System.err(1776):     at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:45)

W/System.err(1776):     at com.roundmesa.twitter.TwitterLoginTask.doInBackground(TwitterLoginTask.java:45)

W/System.err(1776):     at com.roundmesa.twitter.TwitterLoginTask.doInBackground(TwitterLoginTask.java:1)

W/System.err(1776):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)

W/System.err(1776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

W/System.err(1776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

W/System.err(1776):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)

W/System.err(1776):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)

W/System.err(1776):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)

W/System.err(1776):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Somebody else found this error? (It must be absolutely for newbies but i couldn't find nothing similar out there...

Thanks!

Comment: The answer you've selected is not an answer but a question actually, just FYI.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me as well recently. The problem is that Twitter started refusing regular connections and by default, Scribe does not use SSL. The fix is fairly simple: instead of using the regular Scribe Twitter API class, use the SSL one:

```
final OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
.provider(**TwitterApi.SSL.class**)
.apiKey(...)
.apiSecret(...)
.callback(...)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [Twitter rejects my Oauth Request using scribe-java with "SSL is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763702/twitter-rejects-my-oauth-request-using-scribe-java-with-ssl-is-required).

> Since the author of scribe has some objections against adding more and
>   more Social Apis, perhaps [github.com/hhru/subscribe](http://github.com/hhru/subscribe) (a fork of scribe)
>   could be an alternative in several cases.