# Twitter rejects my Oauth Request using scribe-java with "SSL is required"

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, scribe

When trying to execute `service.getRequestToken()` from scribe library (Version 1.3.5) for using oauth with twitter api I always get "SSL is required" as response.

I have already checked all my configurations but there is `https` everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version **1.3.5** of scribe-java, the method `getRequestTokenEndpoint()` of `TwitterApi` uses the non-SSL version of the URL.

In version **1.3.6** this has been fixed. Unfortunetaly, this version has not yet made its way to the downloads section (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe). So one has to build the current version by himself unless it is available there.

Comment: Since the author of scribe has some objections against adding more and more Social Apis, perhaps https://github.com/hhru/subscribe (a fork of scribe) could be an alternative in several cases.

Answer (score 1):

try put:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
.provider(TwitterApi.SSL.class)
.apiKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
.apiSecret("YOUR_API_SECRET")
.callback("YOUR_CALLBACK")
.build();
```

Comment: As I said - the problem has been fixed in 1.3.6 - it was just missing from the download area at the time I asked the question